# Why couldn't deduce const& template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, parameters, non-type

Consider this code:

```
constexpr int TEN = 10;

template < const int& >
struct Object { };

template < const int& II >
void test(Object<II>) { }
```

Then the calls:

```
test<TEN>(Object<TEN>{}); // passes
test(Object<TEN>{}); // FAILS
```

The second call fails to compile with error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘test(Object<TEN>)
note: candidate: template<const int& II> void test(Object<II>)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘II’
```

The question is why? Is it according to the standard?

And the more important question is: how can I workaround this? That is: how can I help the compiler to deduce the `const int&` template parameter?

In the real code instead of `int` I have more complex `literal type`, so I do need the `const&`. Thus I can't just "use `int` instead of `const int&`".

I am using `gcc-7.0.1` (the snapshot) and I am getting the same error with options `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++14`, `-std=c++17`.

Comment: That's a GCC bug. There is no reason this shouldn't work, neither technically nor formally.

Comment: @Columbo Except for core issue 2091, which wasn't fixed until Oulu.

Comment: Look like a regression since 4.9; 4.8 accepts if `TEN` is given external linkage.

Comment: @T.C.: That's fair. I only looked at the WP, didn't know that was subject to a DR.