# Bug in gcc-7 with variadic non-type const& template parameters

Tags: c++11, gcc, variadic-templates, specialization, non-type

Consider [this](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(colouriseAsm:'0',compileOnChange:'0'),source:'template+%3C+const+int%26...+%3E+struct+AA%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3C+%3E+struct+AA%3C%3E+%7B+%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3C+const+int%26+II,+const+int%26...+Is+%3E%0Astruct+AA%3CII,Is...%3E+%7B+%7D%3B%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g7snapshot,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7+(snapshot)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) code:

```
template < const int&... > struct AA;

template < > struct AA<> { };

template < const int& II, const int&... Is >
struct AA<II,Is...> { };
```

This fails with gcc-7.0.1 with error message like `partial specialization is not more specialized`. Is this a bug or something is wrong with this code? Is there a workaround for it?

Comment: clang++5.0 and g++6.3 compile your code happily. Could be a regression...

Comment: A lot of things in the standard depend on deduction, including partial ordering of function templates and class template partial specializations. If GCC gets the deduction wrong - as we know it does from the question you asked a few days ago - then it's unsurprising that it gets the other things wrong too.

Comment: @T.C. What question you mean?

Comment: @Vahagn: probably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111351/why-couldnt-deduce-const-template-parameter)

Comment: By the way, make sure you report confirmed bugs (and snippets that are *very likely* bugs) on the [**gcc bug tracker**](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/). This applies to your previous questions as well - just make sure to do a quick search beforehand to avoid reporting duplicates

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I would like to, but I am not registered there. It says "User account creation filtered due to spam.". Could you advice how to register?

Comment: @Vahagn: I see. Does [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/createaccount.cgi) work?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I sent my email. Last time somewhat a month or two ago, but got no response.

Comment: @Vahagn: that's quite sad. I can submit the bugs on your behalf if you're fine with it (crediting you for the discovery). If that's the case, feel free to send me an email with a list of question/snippets of confirmed/very-likely bugs and I'll submit them. Regardless, you should send an email to *overseers (at) gcc.gnu.org* and ask them to activate your account

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I am totally fine with that. I've posted here the bugs I was stuck with. For the upcoming ones I'll send an email. Thanks.

Comment: Sending an email to overseers is currently the normal process for creating a bugzilla account for gcc.

Comment: Reported as [bug #79470](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79470)